# Problema con validaciones en formulario reactivo

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formularios, reactiveformsmodule

tengo un formulario de registro de usuario, quiero agregar en el input de contraseña que debe tener minimo 8 caracteres, 2 numero, y 2 caracteres especiales y lo tengo de esta forma:

```
     password: ['', [Validators.compose([
 PasswordValidators.patternValidator(new RegExp(`(?=.*[0-9]{2}})`), { requiresDigit: true }),
 PasswordValidators.patternValidator(new RegExp(`(?=.*[$@^!%*?&}]{2}})`), { requiresSpecialChars: true })
            ]), Validators.minLength(8)]],
```

validador:

```
  static patternValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {

        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
            if (!control.value) {
                return null;
            }
            const valid = regex.test(control.value);
            return valid ? null : error;
        };
    }
```

el problema que tengo es que se deben poner los 2 numeros o los 2 caracteres especiales juntos
ejemplo: password12$$
asi me dice que esta valido
pero si meto: pa$ss1wor2d$
me dice que no es valido ya que no son seguidos los numeros ni los caracteres, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con este regex, aquí te dejo mi código:

```
  regex = /^(?=(?:[^0-9]*\d){2})(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]*[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]){2}).*$/;

  formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    password: ['', [
      Validators.required, 
      this.patternValidator(this.regex, { error: true })
    ]]
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  patternValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors) {
     return (control: AbstractControl) => {
       if (!control.value) {
         return null;
       }
       
       const valid = regex.test(control.value);
       return valid ? null : error;
    };
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
   console.log(this.formGroup.valid);
  }
```

Comment: Me ayudo bastante, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema sería con el patrón de validación, este debería de funcionar. Lo probé con un tester de regex online.

```
password: [
  "",
  [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(
      /^(?=.*[A-Za-z]{8,})(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&].*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/
    ),
  ],
];
```